# Display rows in text-area in reverse

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a basic little HTML5 project going on that I took a small snipped of you can see here: http://gyazo.com/4f3b37bc14b06344240ff8f4e48c9e79

What I'm trying to do is make it so that the next text appears at the bottom of text-box, instead of at the top, basically a `bottom-to-top` text-area, but I can't find any information on it. I'm generating all of this using DOM in Javascript, but just a plain old HTML/CSS example would suffice.

Reading chat form top->bottom feels really strange, and I have no idea how to go about this, was thinking about just writing a custom container for text in webgl, but that's performance wasted.

Comment: What are you doing currently to add the text so that it is added on top?

Comment: Maybe you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Don't use a textarea. Just use a Div and align the text to your liking.

Comment: Please add code to your question instead of linking to an off-site resource containing your code.

Comment: @AeroX and that is not code in that link...

Comment: "What are you doing currently to add the text so that it is added on top?" - That's default behavior...

Comment: @Christian.tucker Default behavior of a text-box is to display text. You are trying to "make it so the next text appears" - so you are doing something to add text. This is not default behavior, it's something you must do manually. Basically, yeah - always show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you append the text to the top not the bottom.

```
var txt = document.getElementById("yourId");
txt.value = "New String" + "\n" + txt.value;
```

---

And what I think you actually are after

```js
function hasVertScrollbar(elem) 
{ 
    //see if there is a scrollbar, return true if there is
    return elem.clientHeight < elem.scrollHeight;
}

function addMessage (str) {
    
    var textarea = document.getElementById("txtArea");
    
    //remove all of the padding if there
    var val = textarea.value.replace(/^\n+/,"");
    //update the value with the new message
    val += (new Date()).toLocaleTimeString() + ": " + str + "\n";
    textarea.value = val;
  
    //Create a loop where we add a line break, Loop until we have a scrollbar.     
    var padding = [];
    while (!hasVertScrollbar(textarea)) {
       padding.push("\n");
       textarea.value = "\n" + textarea.value;
    }
    //After the loop we have one too many, so chop off the extra
    padding.pop();
    //update the textarrea with the padding and updated text
    textarea.value = padding.join("") + val;
    //scroll to bottom
    textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
}

function chat(e) {
    var msg = document.getElementById("message");
    addMessage(msg.value);
    msg.value = "";
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;    
}

document.getElementById("frm").addEventListener("submit", chat, false);
```

```css
#txtArea { width: 275px; height: 300px; display: block; }
```

```html
<form id="frm">
    <textarea id="txtArea" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
    <label for="message">Message: </label><input type="text" id="message" /><button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Now the problem with using a textarea is you are not going to be able to use different colors for different users. If you really want to do that, you are going to have to use a div and insert brs or set top padding of the first element.

Comment: Thanks for the highly detailed answer with a runnable snippet. I didn't realize that I needed to provide code for a standard html text-area to not get down-voted to hell. This is exactly what I wanted, coloring doesn't bother me one bit. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Use a div instead of a textarea... it will give you more options.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: table;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.textarea {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  overflow: auto;
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="textarea">
    Here is some text that somebody sent to the chat area...
  </div>
</div>

<input type="text" placeholder="Type your message here"></input>
<button>Send</button>
```

Comment: Great alternative, I would select two correct answers if I could.